# Search across all columns in a table

Tags: full-text-search, sqlite, where

As the title says, I want to create a query that searches a keyword across all columns in that table.

So I want to simplify this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tblCustomers
    WHERE (col1 LIKE '%keyword%' OR col2 LIKE '%keyword%' OR col3 LIKE '%keyword%' OR col4 LIKE '%keyword%') 
    AND (col1 LIKE '%keyword2%' OR col2 LIKE '%keyword2%' OR col3 LIKE '%keyword2%' OR col4 LIKE '%keyword2%');
```

To something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tblCustomers
    WHERE (allColumns LIKE '%keyword%') 
    AND (allColumns LIKE '%keyword2%');
```

Comment: This would be easy with a [full-text search index](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html).

Comment: Shouldn't it say `anyColumns LIKE '%keyword%'`?

Answer (score 1):

## Full Text Search

You can use [FTS5](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html)

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE customer USING tblCustomers(col1, col2, col3);
```

Then you just

```
SELECT * FROM tblCustomers WHERE email MATCH 'keyword AND keyword2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if `PRAGMA` isn't an option:

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master
WHERE tbl_name = 'tblCustomers' 
  AND type = 'table'
  AND (sql LIKE '%keyword%' OR sql LIKE'%keyword2%')
```

Using `AND` for both keyword possibilities seems like it wouldn't work as both won't be true.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the FTS5 approach above working but the following does:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE vtblCust USING FTS5(v_rowid, v_col1, v_col2, v_col3);

INSERT INTO vtblCust(v_rowid, v_col1, v_col2, v_col3) 
SELECT id, title, name, email FROM tblCustomers;

SELECT * FROM vtblCust WHERE vtblCust MATCH 'keyword1 AND keyword2';
```

Note that FTS5 may be optional or disabled in your implementation - see the SQLite documentation for more: https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html. 
Simplest just to try it to see if it works.